# Access written Text in QuillJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, quill

I am using [Quill JS](http://quilljs.com/) as a rich text editor. I want to be able to highlight specific words in the text, if the user clicks a button. But it seems as Quill JS does not give permission to edit its contents by another plugin (?)

I tried [Mark.js](https://markjs.io/) and [Highlight.js](http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html), but they will only work on elements which are not in the Quill JS editor. The trigger seems to work though, since the

line with the correct keyword flashes in Firefox Inspector, like there is something accessing that line, but in the browser there is no real change.

I posted a little example code (**please ignore the first part of the Javascript** since it is just the highlight.js plugin I had to put there. My custom code is at the very end):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  
  // My custom code is at the very end. This is the highlight.js plugin code:
  // Copyright (c) 2009 Bartek Szopka
  jQuery.extend({
    highlight: function (node, re, nodeName, className) {
        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            var match = node.data.match(re);
            if (match) {
                var highlight = document.createElement(nodeName || 'span');
                highlight.className = className || 'highlight';
                var wordNode = node.splitText(match.index);
                wordNode.splitText(match[0].length);
                var wordClone = wordNode.cloneNode(true);
                highlight.appendChild(wordClone);
                wordNode.parentNode.replaceChild(highlight, wordNode);
                return 1; //skip added node in parent
            }
        } else if ((node.nodeType === 1 && node.childNodes) && // only element nodes that have children
                !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName) && // ignore script and style nodes
                !(node.tagName === nodeName.toUpperCase() && node.className === className)) { // skip if already highlighted
            for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
                i += jQuery.highlight(node.childNodes[i], re, nodeName, className);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
});

jQuery.fn.unhighlight = function (options) {
    var settings = { className: 'highlight', element: 'span' };
    jQuery.extend(settings, options);

    return this.find(settings.element + "." + settings.className).each(function () {
        var parent = this.parentNode;
        parent.replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
        parent.normalize();
    }).end();
};

jQuery.fn.highlight = function (words, options) {
    var settings = { className: 'highlight', element: 'span', caseSensitive: false, wordsOnly: false };
    jQuery.extend(settings, options);
    
    if (words.constructor === String) {
        words = [words];
    }
    words = jQuery.grep(words, function(word, i){
      return word != '';
    });
    words = jQuery.map(words, function(word, i) {
      return word.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
    });
    if (words.length == 0) { return this; };

    var flag = settings.caseSensitive ? "" : "i";
    var pattern = "(" + words.join("|") + ")";
    if (settings.wordsOnly) {
        pattern = "\\b" + pattern + "\\b";
    }
    var re = new RegExp(pattern, flag);
    
    return this.each(function () {
        jQuery.highlight(this, re, settings.element, settings.className);
    });
};

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // My custom code
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
 // Initialize Quill editor options
 var toolbarOptions = [
   ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],        // toggled buttons
 ];
 
 // Setup Quill editor
 var options = {
  
   modules: {
  toolbar: toolbarOptions
   },
   placeholder: 'Start writing demo and another word then hit the green div...',
   theme: 'snow'
 };
 var editor = new Quill('#editor', options);
 
 // Use highlight js to highlight every "demo" in the text
 $("#clicker").on("click", function() {
  $("p").highlight("demo");
 });
 
 
});
```

```css
 #clicker {
   background-color: #ddffdd;
   display: block;
   padding: 32px;
   text-align: center;
   }

    .highlight {
        background-color: #FFFF88;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Prototype</title>
    <meta name="description" content="This is a  demo page.">

    <link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.1.5/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.1.5/quill.js"></script>
 

</head>

<body>
  <div id="clicker" style="cursor: pointer">Mark "demo" in Text by clicking here</div>
 <main>
  <div id="editor"></div>
  <div>
   <p>demo outside of editor</p>
  </div>
 </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Heyy you got answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Arbitrary changes through DOM APIs are not supported. To make changes to Quill's editor contents, you have to use its [API](http://quilljs.com/docs/api/). This [Cloning Medium with Parchment](http://quilljs.com/guides/cloning-medium-with-parchment/) guide is useful for creating new formats like what you are describing.

Comment: Okay, thanks to the Documents you linked I managed to create my custom span with  **node.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: lime');**
But how can I close the span again? **quill.format('background', false)** does not work.